# How to calculate Noncentral t-distribution

Tags: math.net

Using MathDotNet, which class would I use to calculate a Non Central T-Distribution?

I'm guessing the Student T class but can't workout the parameter required.

Thanks

Comment: Look [HERE](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/master/src/Examples/ContinuousDistributions/StudentTDistribution.cs)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation examples.  I have been through those, but they relate to Normal Distribution that is centralised.  I'm looking to use the class with a Non-Central distribution.  So looking for a parameter or example where you can move the normal.

Comment: @AndrewStewart Hi, i need to generate from a shifted t distributiob. do you have an examples where i can exprees shifting with non centrality . because this si the only way